# Can you Use useContext twice for two different Contexts in the Same Functional Component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, use-context

Can the `useContext` hook be used twice, for two different contexts, in the same functional React component?

In the [React docs useContext Hooks API Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext), we are given this tip:

> If you’re familiar with the context API before Hooks,
> `useContext(MyContext)` is equivalent to `static contextType = MyContext`
> in a class, or to `<MyContext.Consumer>`.

The "or" there is a bit unclear; it doesn't inform us if multiple hooks are allowed for functional components. For example, in the [React docs on Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), we are told that using `static contextType = MyContext` does not allow us to subscribe to multiple contexts:

> You can only subscribe to a single context using this API. If you need
> to read more than one see Consuming Multiple Contexts.

Presumably, what the [React docs useContext Hooks API Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) meant by "or" in the above statement is that if you use multiple `useContext` hooks then it's allowed, and is equivalent to using multiple consumers as described in [Consuming Multiple Contexts](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#consuming-multiple-contexts).

#### Related Question

There is another related question on this site: [Use multiple...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62720149/5134722). By title, it looks like a duplicate. By content & existing answers, it doesn't seem to be.

Answer (score 3):

Yes; empirically I can say that using multiple context hooks for different contexts in the same component works. Here are some code snippets demonstrating this, in Typescript. First, here's the app that creates the contexts and wraps children in providers:

```
//App.tsx
export const ThemeContext = React.createContext<Theme>(null);
export const OtherContext = React.createContext<string>('');

export function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <ThemeContext.Provider value={themes.light}>
                <OtherContext.Provider value="Hello World!">
                    <Toolbar />
                </OtherContext.Provider>
            </ThemeContext.Provider>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Next we have an intermediate component, just to show that contexts will drill down more than one level:

```
//toolbar.tsx
export function Toolbar() {
    return (
        <div>
            <ThemedButton />
        </div>
    );
}
```

And at the bottom we have a component consuming both contexts:

```
//themedButton.tsx
const { useContext } = React;

export function ThemedButton() {
    const theme = useContext(ThemeContext);
    const other = useContext(OtherContext);

    return (
        <button
            style={{ background: theme.background, color: theme.foreground }}
        >
            I am styled by theme context, and I am also picking up other value: {other}
        </button>
    );
}
```

Full code available on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-usecontext-example-forked-er1fyy?file=/src/App.tsx).